# Set Lwjgl 3 with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl

I have been programming in lwjgl 3 with IntelliJ for a while. To do this I put the jars and the natives in the same folder, and then I added that folder as a Library in the Project Settings, and that worked fine. But the other day I decided to update my lwjgl to a newer version, but the thing is that I found that the natives in the jars are encripted like this:

```
liblwjgl.so.sha1
```

So I cant just move them to the folder, IntelliJ doesnt recognize them.
How I am suposed to correctly set Lwjgl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm stupid, after losing an hour of my life I noticed that in the zip file there are some natives jar from which you can get the non-encrypted natives. Although I do not understand why they made this change.

Answer (score -1):

Try using gradle, it makes it very easy (for more info see [gradle](https://gradle.org/)).

LWJGL provide a way to customize your download and generate the gradle file you need.

You can use this to gather the needed dependencies.

```
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-${osversion}"
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.1.3"
project.ext.jomlVersion = "1.9.9"

dependencies {
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:${lwjglVersion}"
    compile "org.joml:joml:${jomlVersion}"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:${lwjglVersion}"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-jemalloc:${lwjglVersion}"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:${lwjglVersion}"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:${lwjglVersion}"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:${lwjglVersion}"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:${lwjglVersion}:$lwjglNatives"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:${lwjglVersion}:$lwjglNatives"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-jemalloc:${lwjglVersion}:$lwjglNatives"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:${lwjglVersion}:$lwjglNatives"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:${lwjglVersion}:$lwjglNatives"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:${lwjglVersion}:$lwjglNatives"

}
```